# How to get old variable value from PL/SQL for loop?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to get old value from variable in PL/SQL for loop.

For instance:

I have l_sequnce variable with increment of 10.

```
for x in (select name 
          from test_names
          order by position)
loop 

 -- print l_sequnce variable

 -- when name is already was in loop then write same value from l_sequence as for first one

end loop;
```

I hope I described the problem well :)

Comment: Sort your input data and retrieve new value from sequence only when new name arises. But the purpose of this code (with repetitive name) and such usage of sequence is quite strange.

Comment: @astentx in my code l_sequence is y-axis which is element position. and name is role name :)

Comment: Sequence is for number (key) generation, so when you run this code multiple times, it will advance its currval/nextval to the number of processed elements. Better approach for sequential numbering is `dense_rank` which is provided in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT` statement and then you only need to check if the value has changed between the previous and current values:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_name     TEST_NAMES.NAME%TYPE := NULL;
  l_sequence PLS_INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (select name from test_names ORDER BY name)
  LOOP
    IF    x.name <> v_name
       OR (x.name IS NULL AND v_name IS NOT NULL)
       OR (x.name IS NOT NULL AND v_name IS NULL)
       OR l_sequence = 0
    THEN
      l_sequence := l_sequence + 10;
      v_name := x.name;
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_sequence || ': ' || x.name);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Or, don't use PL/SQL and do it all in an SQL statement using the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT name,
       10 * DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS seq_value
FROM   test_names
ORDER BY name; -- or whatever other column you want to order by.
```

---

If you want to do it entirely in PL/SQL and cannot use `ORDER BY` then use an associative array:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_name_seq_map IS TABLE OF PLS_INTEGER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);

  v_names    t_name_seq_map;
  l_sequence PLS_INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT name FROM test_names ORDER BY position)
  LOOP
    IF NOT v_names.EXISTS(x.name) THEN
      l_sequence := l_sequence + 10;
      v_names(x.name) := l_sequence;
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_names(x.name) || ': ' || x.name);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

or:

```sql
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (
    SELECT name,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS l_sequence
    FROM   test_names
    ORDER BY position
  )
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x.l_sequence || ': ' || x.name);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I already have the order by position(sequence of elements), so I can't use order by name.

Comment: For example, I need to assign l_sequence from first record to 4th.

Comment: @Goku Just use `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name)` and then at the end of the query `ORDER BY` whatever different column you want. Don't try doing it all in PL/SQL as you'll just end up with something much more complicated (probably storing names and sequences in associative arrays).

Comment: DENSE_RANK() works perfectly, but when I use in PLSQL code with into clause, I got: ORA-01422 :fetch returns more than requested number of rows. I tried with where clause but, then value is always the same.

Comment: @Goku You do not need to use an `INTO` clause. Just add `DENSE_RANK` to your query in the `FOR` loop as another column. (Or do not use PL/SQL at all and just use an SQL query.)